Swapping $\limsup$ and $\liminf$
I was reading a paper and basically a more specific version of the following came up. Let $(a_{n,m})_{n,m}$ be a positive double sequence. Suppose $a_{n,m} \leq 1$ for all $n$ and $m$ and $\lim_m a_{n,m} =1$ for all $n$. Furthermore, $a_{n,m}$ is increasing in $m$ for all $n$.  Then authors use the following:
\begin{equation}\label{as}
\limsup_n \liminf _m a_{n,m} \leq \liminf_m \limsup_n a_{n,m}.
\end{equation}
It is easy to see that
$$
\limsup _n \inf_{m \geq k} a_{n,m} \leq \inf_{m\geq k} \limsup_n a_{n,m}
$$
or
$$
\sup_{n \geq k} \liminf_m a_{n,m} \leq \liminf_m \sup_{n \geq k} a_{n,m}.
$$
However, I cannot see how to implement the second limits. It intuitively somewhat makes sense that the best subsequence in one variable after taking the worst subsequence in the other one is greater than the other way around. Any help is appreciated.

This inequality is not true. Take
$$
a_{m,n} := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } m \ge n\\
0 & \text{ if } m<n.\end{cases}.
$$
Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{mn} = 0$, $\lim_{m\to\infty} a_{mn}=1$, etc.
Note that the inequality is true if one replaces $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ by $\inf$ and $\sup$.

Daw, very good answer, I like it very much (+1).
